# C# flatten a list of objects with a list property

Tags: c#, linq, flatten

Given the following object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string Age {get; set;}

    public list<string> Interests {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a nice one line linq way to flatten this (I'm open to extension methods) so that if for example we have

```
var People = new List<Person>(){
    new Person(){
        Name = "Bill",
        Age  = 40,
        Interests = new List<string>(){"Football", "Reading"}
    },
    new Person = new List<Person>(){
        Name = "John",
        Age = 32,
        Interests = new List<string>(){ "Gameshows", "Reading"}
    },
    new Person = new List<Person>(){
        Name = "Bill",
        Age = 40,
        Interests = new List<string>(){ "Golf"} 
    }
}
```

We can get a result of (i.e, AddRange to the `Interests` list property if other properties match):

```
{
    {
        Name = "Bill",
        Age  = 40,
        Interests = {"Football", "Reading", "Golf"}
    },
    {
        Name = "John",
        Age = 32,
        Interests = { "Gameshows", "Reading"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean by flattening to put each Interest on a separate line?

Comment: @jdweng No sorry, not flattening the object - just making sure there's not multiple of the same object because the list property has additional values in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`:

```
List<Person> People = ...

var result = People
  .GroupBy(person => new {
     person.Name,
     person.Age 
   })
  .Select(chunk => new Person() {
     Name      = chunk.Key.Name,
     Age       = chunk.Key.Age,
     Interests = chunk
       .SelectMany(item => item.Interests)
       .Distinct()
       .ToList()
   })
  .ToList(); // if we want List<People>
```

Comment: Thanks, `SelectMany` is what I'm after :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` and `SelectMany` to concatenate the interests

```
People.GroupBy(c => new
        {
            c.Name,
            c.Age
        })
       .Select(g => new Person() 
                  { Name = g.Key.Name, 
                    Age = g.Key.Age,
                    Interests = g.SelectMany(r => r. Interests).ToList()})
```